# Possible reason why Xbee is not able to send data

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am using an Arduino Pro Mini 328P (3.3v, 8Mhz) with Xbee series 1. I have set the frequency to 1 Mhz and the baudrate to 9600. Also I have set baudrate to 9600 in the Xbee. I have also tested that at this baudrate Xbee is sending the data properly in a normal scenario.

Now what I have done in my project:

I have registered my Xbee with the gateway and then it will go to sleep (I have used pin hibernate mode) then it will wake up by a digital pin of the Pro Mini. I have put a delay of 19ms, after which the Xbee will try to send data. After sending the data it will go back to sleep.

The problem is that it behaves randomly when sending data to the gateway (which also has the same Xbee series1). Sometimes it sends the data perfectly, sometimes sending fails. I have also enabled RR to retry 6 times in case the Xbee fails to send the data the first time.

I have no idea how to solve this problem because of the randomness in sending the data.

I have put two Xbees nearer (I have two nodes with the same hardware and the same code). There is an interval between of around 4 minutes. So when one Xbee sends the data perfectly, after that 4 minutes gae (time difference of two RTC on different nodes) the other one fails to send the data. In this condition what can I conclude?

As a side note, the Xbee will try to send the data every hour. To calculate that hour I have to use an RTC, which seems to work fine (I am sure because I have taken the logs, the RTC never fails to generate an interrupt).

So I am wondering what could be the possible reason and how can I fix this problem (without restarting anything if it is possible then nothing will be better than that).

And I have no choice to restart my controller.

How to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

A few things.  If possible, increase your baud rate so you spend less time sending data to/from the XBee.  If you have a limited power budget, faster baud rates save time and energy.  I don't know how the UARTs work on the Arduino, so I can't say whether 115,200bps is possible with a 1MHz CPU clock.

Second, make sure you wait for the XBee to assert CTS back to the Arduino after you wake it up.  Never send to the XBee unless it's "clear to send".

Third, if you use API mode, you can watch for a "Transmit Status" frame from the local XBee back to the Arduino which will let you know when the module has successfully sent the frame, and it's safe for you to put it back to sleep.